# How to use @ReCaptcha with Ajax Form in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, captcha

I am trying to use ReCaptcha from `Microsoft.Web.Helpers`. If I load the entire page it renders correctly, but if I load the page with an ajax request it disappears.

Example (/home/index)

```
<div id="bla">
    @Ajax.ActionLink("reload with ajax", "index", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "bla" })

    @ReCaptcha.GetHtml(publicKey: "xxx")
</div>
```

If I enter `/home/index` the captcha appears. If I click the button `reload with ajax` the ReCaptcha disappears...

[image: recaptcha]

1. The page is loaded for the first time
2. `reload with ajax` was clicked, the contents of the page change to `/home/index`, in other words, the entire page reloaded asynchronous and the captcha is gone

Is there a way to fix this or a decent captcha helper for MVC 3?

Comment: See if this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/2524847/273200

Comment: @Bala Yes, that work around solved the problem

Comment: just post what you had to do as an answer if you think it will help others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've replaced the helper with `javascript`. [ReCaptcha script](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js?)

```
<div id="captcha"></div>

<input type="submit" value="Send" />

<script type="text/javascript">
Recaptcha.destroy();
Recaptcha.create("publicKey", "captcha", {});
</script>
```

And the Controller is still the same

```
if (ReCaptcha.Validate("privateKey"))
{
}
```

So when it loads the view partially it executes this scripts and render correctly every time.

Thanks for the help @Bala R

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and the quickest solution i found is using what it is proposed above and add to it this part of code in the top of your page within the handler "EndRequestHandler" proposed by the .net javascript api ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028(v=vs.100)).

With this solution the backend validation always works.

Here is the code I've used :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
  function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            if (Recaptcha != null) {
                     Recaptcha.destroy();
                     Recaptcha.create("public_key", "captcha", {});
                  }
              }
</script>
```

I hope this could help someone...